# Как исправить ошибку в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyowm

При выполнения кода, вылезает ошибка, но при выполнении этого кода не в телеграмм боте всё отлично.
p.s бот на хостинге pythonanywhere поэтому python 2.7 (возможно поэтому и ошибка, у меня 3.8)
код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, """
В каком городе вы хотите узнать погоду?
""")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_weather_step)

def process_weather_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_text = message.text
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(str(user_text))
    w = observation.get_weather()

    temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
    status = w.get_detailed_status()

    response = ('''
В городе '{0}' сейчас:

 * {1} °C
 * {2}
'''.format(user_text,temp,status))

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(response))
```

ошибка:

```
2020-02-26 17:07:36,649 (util.py:66 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "UnicodeEncodeError occurred, args=('ascii', u'\u041c\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a', 0, 5, 'ordinal no
t in range(128)')                                                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 60, in run                                                                           
    task(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                            
  File "bot.py", line 126, in process_weather_step                                                                                                                   
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(str(user_text))                                                                                                               
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)                                                                 
"                                                                                                                                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "bot.py", line 174, in <module>                                                                                                                               
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)                                                                                                                                      
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 392, in polling                                                                  
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)                                                                                                            
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 416, in __threaded_polling                                                       
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()                                                                                                                              
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 109, in raise_exceptions                                                             
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])                                                                                                
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 60, in run                                                                           
    task(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                            
  File "bot.py", line 126, in process_weather_step                                                                                                                   
    observation = owm.weather_at_place(str(user_text))                                                                                                               
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)                                                                 
Exception in thread WorkerThread1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread WorkerThread2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
:                                                                                                                                                                    

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner                                                                                             
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 66, in run                                                                           
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable                                                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner                                                                                             
  File "/home/Qvint01/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 66, in run                                                                           
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4
```

У Вас ошибка в кодировке при преобразовании в строку - `str(user_text)`. Без отладки кода сложно сказать, но предполагаю что проблема именно в стандартной кодировке python версии 2.7 - ascii, а в версии 3.8 - utf-8.

При вызове `str(user_text)` вы не указываете конкретную кодировку через параметр `encoding=`, соответственно используется дефолтная. Узнать какая именно у вас можно с помощью - `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

Comment: Да, но у меня стоит # - *- coding: utf- 8 - *-  в начале.  Да и если добавить encoding='utf-8' ничего не измениться

Comment: sys.getdefaultencoding() - что возвращает?

Comment: Уже решил проблему. Решение было очень лёгким. Во все строки где вылезала ошибка нужно было добавить u перед началом. u'fixed!'